# Storing a list of unicode strings in a csv file python 2

Tags: python, list, csv, unicode

I created a function(`parse_html(param)`) that returns a list like below,

```
list = [u'John', u'Muchia', u'Prozessoptimierung Fahrwiderst\xe4nde']
```

if I return `print list[2]`, and in my function, it gives me `Prozessoptimierung Fahrwiderstände` which is perfect, but it appears differently when in a list

The problem lies when I return the whole list `return list` I want to avoid the 'u'. I want to store a list of strings and the Unicode characters like ä ö and ü should also appear.

fname[x] is the source of the HTML file where x is the file number which is incremented from 0 to count(file_number)

```
list=[]
newlist=[]    
list = parse_html(fname[7])
for row in list:
  drow = row.encode('utf-8')
  newlist.append(drow)
print newlist
```

The goal is to save the returned list to a CSV file. Everytime a new file(fname) is selected, the list is created and should add the new list to the csv file previously created.

I am doing something really wrong and I can realize that and my head hurts. Please help.

### update:

```
for x in range(0,count):
    list = parse_html(fname[x])
    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(list)
```

error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 132: ordinal not in range(1
28)
```

### Answer:

```
wr.writerow([c.encode('utf-8') for c in list]) # instead `wr.writerow(list)
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, and you don't need to remove the `u`. Why do you think you do?

Comment: Hi Daniel, my goal is to save it in a csv. I updated the post a bit, and i think this u is generating a problem

Comment: check out pandas library in python which is nice to handle

Comment: @jorzylicious: Your only problem is that the Python 2 `csv` library is not that good at handling Unicode. See the duplicate.

Comment: No! [Why sys.sysdefaultencoding will break code](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).  Learn to use Unicode correctly instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `u` prefix merely indicates that the string is in Unicode format. There's nothing wrong with your code, and it will behave correctly (as if it didn't have the `u`) in code. It's only output in the print function to let you know it's a Unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSV output code. Since you are using Python 2, you should encode directly to utf-8 before writing:

```
    wr.writerow([c.encode('utf-8') for c in list])
```

Or, upgrade to Python 3 for more integrated unicode support.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: i included 
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
it gives an csv output
wr.writerow([c.decode('utf-8') for c in list])
thanks for the help Daniel.